# Spring Batch - Is there a way to execute a TaskletStep asynchronously?

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous, workflow, spring-batch

I want to trigger an external system process from spring batch TaskletStep and register a callback. When the external process is complete it will signal my original spring batch job and the job will be resumed. I don't want the system which is running the asynchronous step to be sitting idle until the external process is complete.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean here - "I don't want the system which is running the asynchronous step to be sitting idle until the external process is complete."
Could you provide some more details?

Comment: Suppose Host1 is running a tomcat server and each request will start a spring batch job. Now in each spring batch job there two steps, step1 and step2. In step1 I will trigger an asynchronous process. The tomcat server thread which triggered async process in step1 should not wait until the async process is complete but it should take other requests. When the async process is complete the job should be continued.

Answer (score 0):

What you've described is not an asynchronous job. If Step 2 cannot start until the "async" process completes from Step 1, then it's definitely synchronous.

It sounds like your concern is that the Tomcat thread might get stuck waiting for the Spring Batch job to complete. You can avoid that by wrapping your job in a Spring Integration or Camel service, which accepts the request from Tomcat (replying with a 200 OK that the request has been received) and then kicks off your job.